# Visibility of prompt for upgrade to next LTS in MOTD

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, ssh, motd

When I have connected to my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server via SSH, I am greeted with the welcome message and MOTD.

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0 ...)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

New release '18.04.1 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
```

In the last two lines, there’s a prompt to upgrade to the next LTS version, 18.04.1, which has been available for some time now.

But that prompt is *not always* there. Often, it’s not shown.

This doesn’t seem to be related to the availability of other updates (mentioned in the lines above). It doesn’t seem to depend on the type of user signed in (part of administrator group or not), either. I can’t seem to find any pattern of when it is shown and when it isn’t.

Is there any reasonable way that Ubuntu decides whether this should be shown or not? Or is it just shown or hidden randomly?